# HTTP POST request returns Response 200 but no change in state at server

Tags: python, http, python-requests

A function *answer_questions* written for answering a question randomly on [OKcupid](http://okcupid.com). I wrote it as an extension of *User* class in [pyokc](https://github.com/evfredericksen/pyokc)

```
def answer_questions(self):

"""
Submit random answers to questions lying unanswered for
given User. Takes the number of questions to be answered
as argument
"""

    get_questions = self._session.post('http://www.okcupid.com/profile/{0}/questions'.format(self.username))
    tree = html.fromstring(get_questions.content.decode('utf8'))
    new_question = tree.xpath("//*[@id='new_question']")[0]


    # question ID as well as targetid (associated with each User )
    qid = int(tree.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'qtext_')]/@id")[0].split("_")[1])
    targetid = int(tree.xpath("//input[@id='target_userid']/@value")[0])

    number_of_answers = len(new_question.xpath(".//input[contains(@id,'my_answer_')]/@id"))
    number_of_acceptable_answers = len(new_question.xpath(".//input[contains(@id,'their_answer_')]/@id"))


    request_parameters = {
        'ajax': 1,
        'submit': 1,
        'answer_question' : 1,
        'skip' : 0,
        'show_all' : 0,
        'targetid' : targetid,
        'qid' : qid,
        'is_new' :1,
        'answers' : random.randint(1, number_of_answers),
        'matchanswers' : random.randint(1,number_of_acceptable_answers),
        'importance' : 4,
        'is_public': 1,
        'note' : '',
        'delete_note' : 0,
        }

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.74 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }  

    profiles_request = self._session.post('http://www.okcupid.com/profile/{0}/questions/'.format(self.username), data=request_parameters, headers=headers )
    print (profiles_request)
```

The POST request returns response 200 but the question is still shown unanswered on my profile ie no change in state of server.

For a question I answer directly on okcupid, the headers and form data as shown by fiddler are as follows :-

**General**

```
Remote Address:198.41.209.133:80
Request URL:http://www.okcupid.com/questions/ask
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-control:private
CF-RAY:1e7ea9cb7f7d0bb7-HKG
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 17 May 2015 10:33:18 GMT
P3P:CP="NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND UNI COM NAV INT", policyref="http://www.okcupid.com/w3c/p3p.xml"
Server:cloudflare-nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-OKWS-Version:OKWS/3.1.33.0
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:168
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__cfduid=d8678fe61e59e41eb20e760ae5c70a0f71430320840; authlink=5cbd8d4f6953a34e; signup_exp_2014_09_13=2014_simpleblue; override_session=0; session=123132212344212%3a6473645976835253592; nano=k%3Diframe_prefix_lock_1%2Ce%3D1431858786856%2Cv%3D1%7Ck%3Diframe_prefix_lock_2%2Ce%3D1431858856830%2Cv%3D1
Host:www.okcupid.com
Origin:http://www.okcupid.com
Referer:http://www.okcupid.com/questions
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.74 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Form Data**

```
ajax:1
submit:1
answer_question:1
skip:0
show_all:0
targetid:123132212344212
qid:2209
is_new:1
answers:2
matchanswers:2
importance:3
is_public:1
note:
delete_note:0
```

Do you have any suggestion/idea where I am going wrong in my code ?

Comment: Server responds 200 because the developers intends to do so. Ask them, not SO

Comment: Well, its perfectly fine that the response is 200. But then the question should marked as answered in their database.

Comment: You never know how they handle such things - maybe they return some action via JS that have to be executed first. There is not a big deal to return 200 if request comes from other site that theirs - just to deal with hackers like you.

Comment: But the strange thing is that all other POST requests to the website are executed perfectly eg. sending message to other users, retrieving their profile information etc. I will see if they return some action to be executed and update this question accordingly.